Save VS Code Project as Linux User on NetworkFolder
I have a Sambashare on my homeserver where i want to store all my Codeprojects. I want to write the actual code on my main PC. I added the networkfolder to my Windows and can edit the files in VS Code. However when i try to save the files, i am missing the permissions to do so.
How can i setup VS Code to use my Linuxuser to save the files?
I don't want to connect to connect my VS Code via SSH to the Server. If it's possible i would like to edit the files right off the share.
